# jQgrid is awesome but I need only the grid. How?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jqgrid

I have a HTML table (HTML with table is a static file on server). I came across jQgrid to serve my purpose of converting the table to grid. I used a function 'tabletogrid' and was successful.. I liked this plug-in usability. But I have a small issue. I am only concerned about the grid. and I do not need any sorting functionality. I would like to remove few code blocks in JQgrid script and retain only the grid property. Please suggest! I need to minimize the .js files. I do not need unused functions..

Comment: so go through plugin Analise the code and remove those code which you don't want...are you having any problem in that?

Comment: @vivek: Absolutely no problem. That is a good suggestion. Will analyze the JS tonight and try removing few blocks of code...

Comment: @vivek: 'grid.tbltogrid.js' would do the minimum right? just clarifying.. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to the download page of jqGrid you can choose what to include in your script file. If you only need the grid you can just check "grid base".
An alternative would be this [one](http://www.datatables.net/index)

Comment: but dataTables also gives sorting functionality....and you can't remove those codes bcoz they have inner dependency

Comment: jqGrid base minified is 68KB. You only need that and the CSS. If that is still too much I would suggest to style a table by yourself. It's pretty easy http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to modify the jqGrid source code. Instead of that you can use `sortable:false` in every column definition of the grid to switch of sorting in all columns.

If you use the last version of jqGrid you can use new feature introduced in jqGrid 3.8.2: the column template (see [my suggestion](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/feature-request/templates-for-columns-in-colmodel/) in the trirand forum which is implemented with small changes). Because you need to set an additional property in **all columns** of `colModel` you can just use `cmTemplate` parameter as `cmTemplate:{sortable:false}`:

```
tableToGrid('#yourGridId', {cmTemplate:{sortable:false}});
```